# Saving output frame as an image file CUDA decoder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, image-processing, cuda

I am trying to save the decoded image file back as a BMP image using the code in CUDA Decoder project.

```
            if (g_bReadback && g_ReadbackSID)
            {
                CUresult result = cuMemcpyDtoHAsync(g_bFrameData[active_field], pDecodedFrame[active_field], (nDecodedPitch * nHeight * 3 / 2), g_ReadbackSID);



                long padded_size = (nWidth * nHeight * 3 );
                CString output_file;
                output_file.Format(_T("image/sample_45.BMP"));
                SaveBMP(g_bFrameData[active_field],nWidth,nHeight,padded_size,output_file );

                if (result != CUDA_SUCCESS)
                {
                    printf("cuMemAllocHost returned %d\n", (int)result);
                }
            }
```

But the saved image looks like this [image]

Can anybody help me out here what am i doing wrong .. Thank you.

Comment: Try using `cuMemcpyDtoH` rather than `cuMemcpyDtoHAsync` and see if it makes any difference or not.

Comment: nope the output is still same

Comment: in that case you don't have a CUDA programming problem I can see. The only thing which obviously could go wrong is that you are using an asynchronous memory transfer, which might not be finished before you start saving the frame. But that didn't help. So the two choices are either - the data is already wrong coming off the GPU (which probably means it was broken going in), or the save routine expects the data it receives to be different from what you are passing. Nothing you have shown here helps solve either of those two problems.

Comment: The data is reading off back from the window on which the result is showing fine.. I am using the CUDA decoder D3D9 example code and trying to save the frame on read back from the window. They say that the frame is stored here in BYTE* array g_bFrameData[active_field] of which i am trying to save as a bmp file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigating further, there were several modifications I made to your approach.

- `pDecodedFrame` is actually in some non-RGB format, I think it is NV12 format which I believe is a [particular YUV variant](https://www.fourcc.org/pixel-format/yuv-nv12/).
- `pDecodedFrame` gets converted to an RGB format on the GPU using a particular CUDA kernel
- the target buffer for this conversion will either be a surface provided by OpenGL if `g_bUseInterop` is specified, or else an ordinary region allocated by the driver API version of `cudaMalloc` if interop is not specified.

The target buffer mentioned above is `pInteropFrame` (even in the non-interop case).  So to make an example for you, for simplicity I chose to only use the non-interop case, because it's much easier to grab the RGB buffer (`pInteropFrame`) in that case.

The method here copies `pInteropFrame` back to the host, after it has been populated with the appropriate RGB image by `cudaPostProcessFrame`.    There is also a routine to save the image as a bitmap file.  All of my modifications are delineated with comments that include `RMC` so search for that if you want to find all the changes/additions I made.

To use, drop this file in the [cudaDecodeGL](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-video-decoder-gl-api) project as a replacement for the `videoDecodeGL.cpp` source file.  Then rebuild the project.  Then run the executable normally to display the video.  To capture a specific frame, run the executable with the `nointerop` command-line switch, eg. `cudaDecodGL nointerop` and the video will not display, but the decode operation and frame capture will take place, and the frame will be saved in a `framecap.bmp` file.  If you want to change the specific frame number that is captured, modify the `g_FrameCapSelect = 37;` variable to some other number besides 37, and recompile.

[Here is the replacement](http://pastebin.com/VPa40Jf7) for `videoDecodeGL.cpp`  I used pastebin because SO has a limit on the number of characters that can be entered in a question body.

Note that my approach is independent of whether readback is specified. I would recommend not using readback for this sequence.